# How to force Nuxt app to rerender its data on production

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, production, static-site

I'm using Nuxt 2.15 with `target: "static"` and hosting on a shared hosting "hostinger". I fetch the data from an external API using axios and Vuex state management and here comes the problem where the app doesn't load the new data it gets from the API.

How can I make the app rerenders its data and output the newly updated data it gets from fetching the API?

Comment: Hi, you're using Nuxt2 here, with **full static** mode? How do you make the actual call? Is it up to date if you try with Postman? A [repro], some actual code or any additional effort is highly welcome here.

Comment: Hi, 1. some actual code on how you fetch the data would be welcome. 2. Did you tried to generate your app again? 3. What about Postman, does it work there? 4. Do you see any requests in your Network tab (in browser's devtools)? 5. What kind of project do you have here, is it updated often or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using nuxtServerInit or asyncData for getting the data from API. This used with static mode means that data is get only during generation. Which is great for not too often updated content because it doesn't have to connect to server every time it's faster.

Depend on your needs you can:

1. Get data from API in mounted() hook this will get data from API every time the page is loaded **BUT** it also means that it could be loaded with some delay and it probably wouldn't be indexed by search engines
2. You can go with universal mode (https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-mode/) and start your site on node.js server which will use up-to-date data from API each time user will open your site.

EDIT: as @kissu corrected me in comment this one is deprecated, please use this one: `target:'server'` instead of `target:'static'`, which is default so you can just remove this line (https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-target/ )

Comment: `mode` is deprecated as you can see in the link you gave, you probably meant going `ssr: true` and `target: 'server'`. Also, SSG is as universal as SSR.